# Error : 'w' is an unexpected token.WebDeploy Common.Targets

Tags: msbuild, webdeploy

Somehow I can't use WebDeploy anymore. The build log throws the following error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.MSDeploy.Common.targets(55,5): Error : 'w' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space. Line 1, position 2369.

The strange thing is that I haven't changed the file at all. How can I find out to what section the error refers to?

I tried to past the file contents below but this editor keeps formatting it in an unexpected way...

Comment: How are you invoking Web Deploy?

Comment: Solution explorer >> Webproject >> Right mouse click >> Publish

Comment: I did solve the problem a few hours ago but it still puzzles me. I renamed the file to Microsoft.Web.Publishing.MSDeploy.Common.targets_old. I made a new Microsoft.Web.Publishing.MSDeploy.Common.targets and pasted the contents of https://github.com/WaveServiceBus/WaveServiceBus/blob/master/packages/MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.12.0.1/tools/VSToolsPath/Web/Deploy/Microsoft.Web.Publishing.MsDeploy.Common.targets in it. It works like a charm now.

However, i did a file comparisson with Notepad++ and it shows the files are exactly the same. ???